# Grab server (SSL) certificate using WIn32 API

Tags: winapi

I'm relatively new to Win32 programming & I was wondering if there is any thing similar to openssl's s_client; for e.g "openssl s_client -showcerts -connect". Bottom line, I want to grab the server certificate using Win32 API directly. Is that possible?

Comment: openssl s_client is a command line tool for connecting to a server. If you are asking for a tool (rather than a C/C++ api) this should qualify for SU rather than SO?

Comment: I'm asking for a C/C++ api. My curiosity is more because I was just wondering what do they do in Win32 world without Openssl. Obviously, there has to be a way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

The `HttpQueryServiceConfiguration` function lets you query an HTTP server about SSL details. More info here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364491(v=VS.85).aspx

Comment: That query the server *from* the server, not over the network from the client.

Comment: Sorry, that wasn't clear to me from the original post. I suggest the OP is edited to make that explicit.

Comment: CesarGon got it right the first time. I want to replicate openssl s_client feature (specifically to grab server certificate) using Win32 API. I wanted to do this programatically instead of using the openssl tool.